Cron docker container keeps dying with exit code 0- unable to see any logs that can provide the clues needed
I am running multiple docker containers, put on the same network using the same docker-compose. For the container running cron jobs, I started by using "docker build" at the CL, and then added the container to the docker compose. Before adding to the docker-compose, it was working just fine.
I have the commands to start up each container in their own bash script. When I run the bash scripts for the python and sql containers, they start up without any issue.
But when I run the bash script for the cron container, it exits with code 0.
docker-compose_combined.yml

version: "3"

services:
  python_cron_container:
    build:
      context: .
      network: my_network
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile_python
    image: ubuntu:latest
    container_name: python_cron_container
    volumes:
      - /Users/my_name/python_cron_container:/scripts
    restart: always
  datacentral_server:
    build:
      context: .
      network: my_network
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-mysql
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
    container_name: datacentral_server
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: 'username_here'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pword_here'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'pword_here'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql_server/init.d/mysql-dump/schema_dump_2.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema__dump_2.sql
      - ./mysql-data/:/var/lib/mysql/
      - /Users/my_name/python_cron_container:/scripts
      - /Users/my_name/python_cron_container/schema1.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema1.sh
      -  /Users/my_name/python_cron_container/conf.d/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
  cron_container:
     build:
       context: .
       network: my_network
       dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile-cron
     image: ubuntu:18.04
     container_name: cron_container
"docker-compose_combined.yml" 47L, 1391B



docker/Docker-file-cron
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# install cron and vim
RUN apt-get update\
&& apt-get install cron -y && apt-get install vim -y

# install python and some packages
#RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    #cron \
    #python3-setuptools \
    #python3-pip\
    #python3.12-venv\
    #pkg-config\
    #default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    #build-essential \

# Crontab file copied to cron.d directory
COPY ./cronjob etc/cron.d/container_cronjob

# Script file copied into container.
COPY ./script.sh /script.sh

# Giving exectuable permission to script file
RUN chmod +x /script.sh

# sleep
sleep 10
# Running commands for the startup of the container
CMD ["/bin/bash","-c"."/script.sh && chmod 644 etc/cron.d/container_cronjob && cron && tail -f var/log/cron.log"]

# Command to make sure container keeps running
# CMD ["cron", "-f", "-l", "8"] && tail -f /dev/null
RUN tail -f /dev/null
sleep 10
~                  



build_and_runcron.sh
#!/bin/sh
docker container rm cron_container
docker-compose -f docker-compose_combined.yml build --force-rm
docker-compose -f docker-compose_combined.yml up  cron_container



I tried viewing the docker logs, using:
docker logs cron_container

and
docker container logs cron_container


I tried viewing the logs for the docker-compose:
 docker compose logs


They either returned nothing, or something irrelevant ( "version is obsolete" from the compose, but it's not impacting the other containers, just a warning).
I tried viewing the logs on the docker desktop, and I see nothing.
I also made the edits visible in the dockerfile: the sleep command, and the "RUN tail -f /dev/null" command.

In experimenting with this, have you ever had an ENTRYPOINT line?  Does running docker pull ubuntu:18.04 and rebuilding make a difference?  Your Compose file shows three containers; are the other two important to the question at all?

The other two containers are working just fine, I thought I'd show the whole docker compose in case there is some issue I wasn't aware of. I will look into the ENTRYPOINT line, and then try "docker pull ubuntu:18.04".

So I added "ENTRYPOINT ["cron", "-f"]
" which made exactly zero difference. Although, it may be an issue I encountered before, where I break down and restart the same container multiple times, commands in the dockerfile simply cease to run.

The actual issue I'm noting is that you have both Compose build: and image:, and your Dockerfile is built FROM the image:; that means that every build is starting from the previous build and you're not using the Docker Hub image as a base.  That's where docker pull the original image again might help.
